# Tesseract OCR fails on TIFF files

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I have a multiple page `.tif` file, I am trying to extract text from it using Tesseract OCR but I am getting this error

> TypeError: Unsupported image object

**Code**

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract

img = Image.open('Group 1/1_CHE_MDC_1.tif')
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img.seek(0))  # OCR on 1st Page
text = ' '.join(text.split())
print(text)
```

**ERROR**

[image]

Any idea why its happening

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Image.seek` does not have a return value so you're essentially running:

```
pytesseract.image_to_string(None)
```

Instead do:

```
img.seek(0)
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
```

Comment: Hello, On doing changes as per your suggestion I am getting this error `OSError: encoder error -2 when writing image file` https://s15.postimg.cc/8u1z2zksb/error3.png

Comment: @Atinesh: That's a problem with your image, not with pytesseract or PIL. Your code works fine for me with a multipage TIFF file with my changes. Can you upload the original image file somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

I had a same question and i have tried below code and it worked for me :-

import glob
import pytesseract
import os

os.chdir(**"Set your Tesseract-OCR .exe file path"**)

```
b = ''
for i in glob.glob('Fullpath of your image directory/*.tif'):  <-- you can give *.jpg extension in case of jpg image
    if  glob.glob('*.tif'):
        b = b +  (pytesseract.image_to_string(i))
print(b)
```

*Happy learning !*